# AWS CodeBuild times out when downloading dedencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, guava, aws-codebuild

I am deploying a small project in AWS and I am using AWS CodeBuild to build the project. I am using gradle and the [johnrengelman/shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin to deploy the app as a fat jar.

Among my dependencies I have guava-26 which is imported by using the following line:

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '26.0-jre'
```

When I build the project, I get *usually but not always* errors like the following:

```
  Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre.
  Required by:
  project :common
  > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:26.0-jre.
  > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/26.0-jre/guava-26.0-jre.pom'.
     > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/26.0-jre/guava-26.0-jre.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

If I use Guava 25.1 there is not such problem. Anybody having experienced the same or having an explanation?

Comment: At risk of being a "me too" comment.. we're also having the same problem with our aws codebuild projects, so think there's some sort of outage or maven central have blocked codebuild IPs.

Comment: In the end I resorted to connecting codebuild to my VPC and then running maven central through a Nexus instance